# using awk to flatten an xml

Tags: xml, awk, flatten

I would like to flatten xml file with about 20000 lines.

Sample input

```
 <start>                             
     <request>523331111111111</request>   
     <odbs>1</odbs>          
     <request>523331111111112</request>  
     <odbs>0</odbs>          
     <request>523331111111113</request>  
     <odbs>1</odbs>          
     <request>523331111111114</request>                
     <request>523331111111115</request>  
     <odbs>2</odbs>        
 </start>
```

Expected output is

```
523331111111111,1
523331111111112,0
523331111111113,1
523331111111114,none
523331111111115,2
```

Comment: logically, there's no relationship between the first request and the first odbs. You should alter your xml structure: `<start><pair><request>R</request><odbs>O</odbs></pair><pair>...`

Comment: The file was created such a way that, the top request will be paired with odbs below the line (if there's a value for obds) else it is none

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS="[<>]"; OFS="," }
/<request>/ { if (req!="") print req, odbs; req=$3; odbs="none" }
/<odbs>/    { odbs=$3 }
END { if (req!="") print req, odbs }

$ awk -f tst.awk file
523331111111111,1
523331111111112,0
523331111111113,1
523331111111114,none
523331111111115,2
```

The above will work with any awk, will produce the correct output no matter which "odbs" values are missing, including the last one, and will produce no output for an empty input file (always desirable).

Answer (score 2):

awk to the rescue...

There is a typo in your data sample but doesn't matter for this script

```
awk -F "[<>]" -vRS="<request>" -vOFS="," 'NR>1{print $1, $5==""?"none":$5}'
```

Explanation: define records by keyword, split the record, find the matching ones and replace missing value with "none"

Comment: @jimbo, be sure to 'accept' the answer that solves your problem by clicking on the check mark by the up and down arrows on each question. This gives the writer reputation points, and an incentive to keep answering questions ;-) Good luck to all.

Comment: You should mention that solution is gawk-specific courtesy of the multi-char RS, More importantly, it will fail when the last request in the input is missing a subsequent <odbs> line.